# How can I sync with woocommerce categories with my API database via C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have all my products currently being stored on an SQL database that can be accessed via API (currently using C#). I have tested it to make sure it is connected to my wordpress site and can import products and categories. However getting the category nesting isn't working properly. (connecting to parent categories on woocommerce)

I would like to sync my categories so my facets work properly.

**TL'DR: How can I sync with woocommerce categories with my API database.**

This is how my test facets look on my website:

[image]

When I retrieve all my categories using woocommerce API this is an example of what it looks like:

```
 {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "exterior cleaners",
        "slug": "exterior-cleaners",
        "parent": 17,
        "description": "",
        "display": "default",
        "image": null,
        "menu_order": 0,
        "count": 0,
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/18"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
                }
            ],
            "up": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/17"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Super clearner",
        "slug": "super-clearner",
        "parent": 18,
        "description": "",
        "display": "default",
        "image": null,
        "menu_order": 0,
        "count": 0,
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/19"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
                }
            ],
            "up": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/18"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Heavy Duty",
        "slug": "heavy-duty",
        "parent": 0,
        "description": "",
        "display": "default",
        "image": {
            "id": 10,
            "date_created": "2020-10-02T14:45:28",
            "date_created_gmt": "2020-10-02T14:45:28",
            "date_modified": "2020-10-02T14:45:28",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2020-10-02T14:45:28",
            "src": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/gettyimages-172725359-2048x2048-1.jpg",
            "name": "gettyimages-172725359-2048&#215;2048",
            "alt": ""
        },
        "menu_order": 0,
        "count": 3,
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/20"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://beta.demosite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

On my SQL database all my categories already have category ID's in place and parent category ID's. I believe it would be easiest if I override the entire category to match my API. However when it goes through the loop and doesn't find a match it creates a new one, but not the lowest number, it creates the highest number.

Essentially, I want my category ID's to be the same on both database tables.

**Important things to note**

- The category & products on woocommerce will never be changed any other way than via API.
- Woocommerce category ID's can only be read and not changed.
- 

This is what the C# code looks like to insert via API

```
    request.AddJsonBody(new WooCategories {​​​​​​​
                                    name = dmsb.Name,
                                    slug = slug,
                                    parent = dmsb.Parent_category_id,
                                    image = new List<CategoryImage>
                                    {​​​​​​​
                                            new CategoryImage
                                            {​​​​​​​
                                                src = dmsb.Image_url ?? ""
                                            }​​​​​​​
                                        }​​​​​​​
                                }​​​​​​​);
```

**UPDATE 1:**
After digging a little deeper I went into my woocommerce MYSQL terms table and found that ID 1-15 aren't overwritable regardless as they are not categories. I can't figure out the best way to connect the parent categories via API. Here is what the database looks like on woocommerce end.

I feel a potential fix would be doing a nested loop creating slugs with number then connecting the slug numbers as parent category numbers.. What I feel this is a funky way to fix the API problem.
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Discovered it's better to create new tables with a relationship sync of the category ID's so my API has the proper pathing. I will be trying this now, but it is more of a SQL / C# issue.